# PHP Regex - Looking for all symbols except the word

Tags: php, regex

I am using regexp on PHP. I have the text similar to the next(I have simplified it pretty much):

```
<table id="different_every_time" …><a href="url" …>Link</a>
… Intro text<table> … This is place for menu</table>
<table>Content</table></table>
```

I need to grab the text between the first tag and the second  tag
So the result is supposed to be:

```
id="different_every_time" …><a href="url" …>Link</a>… Intro text
```

I have tried next pattern:

```
(?<=<table)(.+)(?=<table)
```

But it returns me everything between the first `<table>` and the last `<table>`. I need to replace (.+) for something like (everything except ).
May be there is easier solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `(.+)` to `(.+?)` to make it *not greedy*. It will try to match as little as possible, instead of as much as possible, ie: *greedy*.